# Move two sortable objects in different list to the same position by their class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists of sortable objects

```
1         1 (1A 1B)
2 (2A 2B) 2 
3         3 (3A 3B)
4 (4A 4B) 4
5         5 (5A 5B)
```

The code for the lists look like this:

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".contain" ).sortable();
 });
```

```css
.contain{
   list-style: none;
}

#right{
   float: left;
}

#left{
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
     <div>
      <ul id="left" class="contain">
       <li class="1">1</li>
       <li class="2">2</li>
       <ul>
           <li>2A</li>
           <li>2B</li>
       </ul>
       <li class="3">3</li>
       <li class="4">4</li>
          <ul>
           <li>4A</li>
           <li>4B</li>
          </ul>
       <li class="5">5</li>
      </ul>
     </div>

     <div>
      <ul id="right" class="contain">
       <li class="1">1</li>
          <ul>
           <li>1A</li>
           <li>1B</li>
          </ul>
       <li class="2">2</li>
       <li class="3">3</li>
          <ul>
           <li>3A</li>
           <li>3B</li>
          </ul>
       <li class="4">4</li>
       <li class="5">5</li>
          <ul>
           <li>5A</li>
           <li>5B</li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to sort the same numbers together. For example, if I were to take the 5 in list "left" and move it to the top, then the 5 in list "right" should also move to the top, and the reverse is true as well if I were to take the 3 from list "right" and move it to the top, then the 3 in list "left" would do the same.

Comment: Is this question a dupe of How to sync jquery sortable lists that contain cloned elements??

We are talking about syncing two lists.

This example, however, has one additional problem. It has nested lists as a main list item. If I were to drag such a nested list, it's child items do not get dragged along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this js in your code and try this answer

```
$(".contain").sortable({
    start:function(event, ui){
        pre = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        lst = $(this).attr('id');
        post = ui.item.index();
        other = (lst == 'left') ? 'right' : 'left';
        if (post > pre) {
            $('#'+other+ ' li.li_parent:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertAfter('#'+other+ ' li.li_parent:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }else{
            $('#'+other+ ' li.li_parent:eq(' +pre+ ')').insertBefore('#'+other+ ' li.li_parent:eq(' +post+ ')');
        }
    }
});
```

your ul should be with in li for eg:- `<li>1<ul><li>a</li></ul></li>` and assign class name `li_parent` for movable `li`.

```js
$(function() {
    var lst, pre;

    $(".contain").sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            pre = ui.item.index();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            lst = $(this).attr('id');
            post = ui.item.index();
            other = (lst == 'left') ? 'right' : 'left';
            if (post > pre) {
                $('#' + other + ' li.li_parent:eq(' + pre + ')').insertAfter('#' + other + ' li.li_parent:eq(' + post + ')');
            } else {
                $('#' + other + ' li.li_parent:eq(' + pre + ')').insertBefore('#' + other + ' li.li_parent:eq(' + post + ')');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.contain{
   list-style: none;
}

#right{
   float: left;
}

#left{
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
     <div>
      <ul id="left" class="contain">
       <li class="1 li_parent">1</li>
       <li class="2 li_parent">2
       <ul>
           <li>2A</li>
           <li>2B</li>
       </ul>
       </li>
       
       <li class="3 li_parent">3</li>
       <li class="4 li_parent">4
         <ul>
           <li>4A</li>
           <li>4B</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
         
       <li class="5 li_parent">5</li>
      </ul>
     </div>

     <div>
      <ul id="right" class="contain">
       <li class="1 li_parent">1
       <ul>
           <li>1A</li>
           <li>1B</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
          
       <li class="2 li_parent">2</li>
       <li class="3 li_parent">3
        <ul>
           <li>3A</li>
           <li>3B</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
         
       <li class="4 li_parent">4</li>
       <li class="5 li_parent">5
       <ul>
           <li>5A</li>
           <li>5B</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
          
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried to add, cancel: 'input,button,[contenteditable]'; into this script but it seems like this line of code makes the script no longer work. Any tips on where to add this line so that the code still can work?

Comment: Based on add button do you want to create dynamic `li` in the above list or can you explain me more by adding comment here or by edit your question